# How to cleanup all autogenerated files?

Tags: perl

To create distribution in perl I use `Module::Build`. And generate meta files by command: `./Build distmeta`

```
Creating Makefile.PL
Creating README using Pod::Text
Creating LICENSE file
Created META.yml and META.json
```

At some point I decide to delete all autogenerated files. I run `./Build distclean`

```
Cleaning up build files
Cleaning up configuration files
```

But metafiles are left: `README`, `LICENSE`

Is there a command to cleanup those files too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `META` files are removed because those are purely generated, but `README` and `LICENSE` are often customized, so they can't be safely removed or overwritten.

If you don't customize `README` and `LICENSE`, and if you insist on having a means of removing them, there is a solution if you use `git`. Don't add the files to the repository (which is made easy by adding them to `.gitignore`), and use `git clean -dfx` (instead of `./Build distclean`) to freshen your directory.

Comment: My requirements better fit `-X` option. I extend your answer a bit. Thank you.